# How to load an ascii file into an array using actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, ascii

My friends, 
As a matter of fact, I am new to AS3. What I want is to read an external text file and then load it into three arrays. The text file has 3 columns, for example, something like this

Freq Mag Phase

2000 10 56

2200 8.2 -140

2600 14  -120

... ... ...

I want three arrays, each of which contains values from each column, for example, "freqArray" should be [2000 2200 2400]  I would really appreciate your help.
There are some useful pieces of code out there. I use the code below, for example, but the problem is that 1) it does not separate spaces between columns, it just separates lines 2) I guess that entries in the array are characters, not numbers.

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("myText.txt");
var myArray:Array = new Array();

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete, false, 0, true);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void{
myArray = myLoader.data.split("\n");

for(var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
    trace(myArray[i]);                         // To check if it works at this point
}

//now move on with the rest of your program/code
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is ***not*** a code-writing service! Show us something that you've tried, and we can maybe help to improve/fix your code.

Comment: Please describe, what are you having problems with - exactly? Loading files? Working with stings? Converting string decimal representation into numbers? Loops? Also please attach the problematic piece of script for the reference and diagnostics.

Comment: My friends, there is an external text file that contains 3 columns. I want to write a code that has 3 arrays each of which contains values from those columns. Entries in columns should be number-like. I mean that I want to work with entries in arrays. I hope this was clarifying.

Comment: @abbashonarmand We quite understand what you want to achieve. What we trying to explain is that such a request (asking for a working code per text description) does not comply with **StackOverflow** ideology. Please read this guideline and edit your question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My Friends, I tried my best to change my question format so that it complies with StackOverflow ideology. Would you mind helping me?

Comment: hm... that looks like it was straight copied from another answer

Answer (score 0):

> I use the code below, for example, but the problem is that...
>
> - (1) It does not separate spaces between columns, it just separates lines
> - (2) I guess that entries in the array are characters, not numbers.

**(1)**
It separates by new line because of your `"\n"`. See [example reference](https://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii).

If you want SPACE instead then just put a space between the quote marks.

```
myArray = myLoader.data.split(" ");
```

**(2)** You can convert text (written as digits) into actual Numbers by **data casting**.

- Set `int` If you want **whole** numbers eg: `myVar = int( myArray[x] ); //x holds the 2200`.
- Set `Number` If you have **fraction** numbers eg: `myVar = Number( myArray[x] ); //x hold 8.2`.

where: `x` is the position, inside Array, that has the value you want to cast.

A faster trick to avoid creating some new variable (`myVar`) might be something like...

```
myArray[x] = int( myArray[x] ); //just overwrite the current text chars with actual integer
```